# Interview Question - Printing the pattern formed by Characters of the given String sorted in Ascending order

Tags: java, string, sorting, hashmap

I was asked this question during an interview.

> Print the pattern of characters from the given word by arranging the characters in ***ascending*** order based on the ***number of occurrencies***.
>
> *Input:* `"abbccbddddeeeee"`
>
> *Output:*
>
> ```
>    a
>    cc
>    bbb
>    dddd
>    eeeee
> ```

I was not able to solve it on the spot, and I can't make my solution working for now.

Specifically, I'm having trouble with arranging in ascending order after populating a `HashMap`.

*My code:*

```
String test = "abbccbdddddddeeeee";
        
List<Character> orderedList = new ArrayList<Character>();
List<Integer> orderedNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
char[] testing = test.toCharArray();
        
int value = 1;
        
Map<Character, Integer> pattern = new HashMap<>();
        
for (int i = 0; i < testing.length; i++) {
    value = 1;
    if (!pattern.containsKey(testing[i])) {
        pattern.put(testing[i], value);
            
        for (int j = i + 1; j < test.length(); j++) {
            if (testing[i] == testing[j]) {
                value = pattern.get(testing[i]);
                value += 1;
                pattern.replace(testing[i], value);
            }
        }
        orderedList.add(testing[i]);
        orderedNumber.add(value);
    }
}
```

This is for the printing part, but as you can see. I have little success in it.

```
System.out.println(orderedList);
System.out.println(orderedNumber);

int minNumber = 0;
int minIndex = 0;
        
for (int i = 0; i < orderedList.size(); i++) {

    minNumber = pattern.get(orderedList.get(i));
    int maxNumber = 0;

    for (int j = i +1; j < orderedList.size(); j++) {
        if (minNumber > pattern.get(orderedList.get(j)))    {
            minNumber = pattern.get(orderedList.get(j));
            maxNumber = pattern.get(orderedList.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(minNumber);
}
```

Comment: `in ascending order of number of occurrence` - what if the number of occurrences of two different characters is the same, what should be the order?

Comment: Are there any constraints regarding input string? Meaning, it might contain any symbols, only English lower case characters, etc.?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I was just given to work on this particular string. But I guess we can improve the code to include all your criteria as well.

Answer (score 1):

With your idea of using `Map` you were on the right track.

## Imperative approach

Main steps:

- Generate a *map* of frequencies for each symbol in the given string.
- Sort the *map* entries based on *values*. Obviously, it's not doable withing a *map*, we need a different collection for that. We can dump map entries into a `List` and sort it.
- Print the contents of the *list*.

That's how it can be implemented:

```
public static void printFrequencyPattern(String str) {

    Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = getFrequencies(str);
    List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> sortedEntries = toSortedEntryList(frequencies);
    
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry: sortedEntries) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey().toString().repeat(entry.getValue()));
    }
}

public static Map<Character, Integer> getFrequencies(String str) {
    Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        frequencies.merge(str.charAt(i), 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    return frequencies;
}

public static List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> toSortedEntryList(Map<Character, Integer> frequencies) {
    
    List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<>(frequencies.entrySet());
    sortedEntries.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
    
    return sortedEntries;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "abbccbdddddddeeeee";
    printFrequencyPattern("abbccbdddddddeeeee");
}
```

*Output:*

```
a
cc
bbb
eeeee
ddddddd
```

## Stream-based Solution

In case if you're comfortable with using Stream IPA, here's a one-liner which everything as the code above within a single statement.

The idea behind the code is mostly the same, *collector* `toMap()` generates a map of frequencies. Then a stream of its *entries* gets created and sorted by *value* of each entry.

```
str.codePoints()
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        ch -> 1,
        Integer::sum
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .forEachOrdered(entry -> 
        System.out.println(Character.toString(entry.getKey()).repeat(entry.getValue()))
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a map for a frequency count is a common practice and a good start.  To demonstrate:

First, create some random data.  I wanted there to be the same number of some elements to allow for sorting in lexical order if the counts were equal (not required based on your question but easy to do).

```
String s = "abbcccddddeeeeffffffggggggg";
List<String> list =
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(s.split("")).toList());
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Now define a comparator to use in the sort - first on count, then on lexical key. Doing it outside the stream avoids clutter.

```
 Comparator<Entry<String, Long>> comp = Entry
                    .<String, Long>comparingByValue()
                    .thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey());
```

Then stream the list and do a `frequency count`. The `key` will be the `letter` and the `count` will be `its frequency of occurrences`.  Take the resulting `entrySet` of the map and sort first based on count, then based on lexical order. Then print using the Entry fields.

```
list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a,
                Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream().sorted(comp)
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(
                e.getKey().repeat(e.getValue().intValue())));
```

prints

```
a
bb
ccc
dddd
eeee
ffffff
ggggggg
```

Comment: I am not that good with comparators and streams but thank you for your answer. I will look into those more.

Comment: So what were you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic counting sort.  You use an array of int to count the occurrence of each character.  Then use the array to print them in ascending order.  The indices 0-26 map to 'a' to 'z'.

Then use counting sort again to sort by occurrence. This works well only if your string isn't too long.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abbccbddddeeeee";
        int[] count = new int[26];
        for(char c: s.toCharArray()) 
           count[c-'a']++;
           
        char[] sort = new char[s.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<count.length; i++) 
           sort[count[i]]=(char)(i+'a');
        
        for(int i=0; i<sort.length; i++){
            if ('a' <= sort[i]  && sort[i] <= 'z'){
              for(int j=0; j<i; j++) 
                System.out.print(sort[i]);
              System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't print the characters in ascending order of number of occurrences.

Comment: I forgot the second part.  It's a matter of sorting.

Comment: Although the data in the question didn't have this condition, if you have two different letters with the same frequency count, you will overwrite any previously saved value with that count.

Comment: You are right.  I did catch that but I don't want to edit it.  It's an easy fix.  Simply use a list to store the pair of count and character and sort the list by count using Collections.sort.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by storing occurrence number per character in a map and then sort the map. After that you can print the map as your pattern.

You have already stored the occurrences in a map.

```
// sort the map. You can do it in any way you like
Map<Character, Integer> sortedMap = pattern.entrySet().stream()
                                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,(e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

//print the pattern
System.out.println(sortedMap);
for(Character key : sortedMap.keySet()){
  for(int i=1; i<= sortedMap.get(key);i++){
    System.out.print(key);
  }
  System.out.println();
  
}
```